# PHP serialize data unserialize in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Is there something like unserialize PHP functions in jQuery?

I have a variable serialized with PHP serialize(). I have to unserialize it with j Query/java script.

Comment: post your serialized array

Comment: What type of data are you trying to serialize in php? is it just normal array?

Comment: Why does it have to be the PHP serialization algorithm? What's wrong with JSON?

Answer (score 10):

Serialise with `json_encode()` in PHP, and deserialise with `JSON.parse()` in Javascript

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

in PHP

```
json_encode(unserialize(SerializedVal));
```

in JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse(JsonString);
```